# How can I get the HTTP_ACCEPT Headers from a browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible HTTP Accept headers using only javascript? I know using PHP I would do something like this `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']`, but as far as I can tell javascript doesn't have this.

Perhaps I could do something with an XmlHttpRequest?

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: "The headers sent to the server."

You could echo them back out in the server's response, and get them that way.

IE.) On a web-page you could make a hidden form field with the value, or pop the value into the javascript that gets emited from the page.

From a web service, you could include the value of the incoming header in part of the outgoing XML or JSON.

If you're using XmlHttpRequest, you could send a header *back* to the client with this value.

Possibilities are endless.

I'm dubious of why this would ever be useful though. The client should know what it's expecting before it requests it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for headers sent *from* the server or *to*?

If you're using Firefox and want to look at or alter headers going from the browser to the server, you might look at [the sources](https://github.com/garethhunt/modifyheaders) for the [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) plugin. It's not pure javascript, but it may help shake something loose.

Comment: The headers sent to the server. I'm getting the impression that this isn't possible.